# PHP Visibility memory usage

Tags: php

I have 2 classes:

```
class MyClass1
{
   private $private1 = 'Private1';
   private $private2 = 'Private2';
   private $private3 = 'Private3';

   function printHello()
   {
       echo $this->private1;
       echo $this->private2;
       echo $this->private3;
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
   public $private1 = 'Private1';
   public $private2 = 'Private2';
   public $private3 = 'Private3';

   function printHello()
   {
       echo $this->private1;
       echo $this->private2;
       echo $this->private3;
    }
}
```

How about memory usage if running these classes? Running `MyClass1` uses less memory than `Myclass2`? Please, note that I ONLY ask about memory usage.

Comment: Take a look at the function: `memory_get_usage()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between access modifiers in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209887/what-is-the-difference-between-access-modifiers-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

> No, access modifiers have no effect on runtime memory utilization in
>   either Java or PHP, nor in any other language I have heard of.
>   Possibly the code size may increase a few bytes due to access
>   modifiers in some bytecodes depending on how they are encoded. Your
>   program must be extremently efficient in other respects before it is
>   worth worrying about this.

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209887/what-is-the-difference-between-access-modifiers-in-php) answer

Comment: Instead of copying the answer, flag this question as duplicate.